# database query returns null for count despite there being rows in the database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

database returns a null, despite there being records in the database

```
     private static final String DATABASE_NAME="PlayGamesdb";
     private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="peopleTable";

   public int fetchPlacesCount() {
        int count = 0;
        //String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HITS };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from DATABASE_TABLE", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        count = c.getInt(0);    
        return count;
    }
```

any ideas on what is wrong?

```
01-24 19:30:23.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 19:30:23.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 19:30:23.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at com.example.dbsample.PlayGame.fetchPlacesCount(PlayGame.java:93)
01-24 19:30:23.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at com.example.dbsample.SQLiteExample.onClick(SQLiteExample.java:123)
01-24 19:30:23.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
```

here is the onclick that in the other class used to call the fetchPlacesCount method

```
 case R.id.bSQLnumberofrows:
        int x = 0;
        PlayGame ec = new PlayGame(this);
        ec.open();
        x = ec.fetchPlacesCount();
        ec.close();
        sqlRow.setText(x);
        break;
```

EDIT:

after fixing the problems the code below is now working and shows the correct number of rows as a Toast message, so now one problem fixed and one more to go,  still error with the setText method for putting the number in the EditText. that is what I will work on next, to see what is wrong with this textView.

using the Toast message was a good way to find out that the method was returning the correct number.

```
public int fetchPlacesCount() {
        int count = 0;
        Cursor q = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
        q.moveToFirst();
       count = q.getInt(0);
        return count;
    }
```

int the other class

```
    case R.id.bSQLnumberofrows:
        PlayGame ec = new PlayGame(this);
        ec.open();
        int x = ec.fetchPlacesCount();
        ec.close();
      //  sqlRow.setText(x);
        Toast.makeText(SQLiteExample.this, "value of x " + x , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
```

Comment: just print cursor.getCount() so that you will get number of rows you are getting from DB are correct. also make query select * from DBName.

Comment: Where is line 93? Could it be that `ourDatabase` is `null`?

Comment: line 93 is; Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from DATABASE_TABLE", null);

Comment: also changed it to Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from DATABASE_TABLE", null);  and the same null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return the `cont` variable instead of `count` as you are not assigning any value to `count` variable.

> ```
> int cont = c.getInt(0); 
>     return cont;
> ```

**EDITED:**

Fire your query as below:

> Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

Comment: not yet. still a null pointer exception on line 93   Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from DATABASE_TABLE", null);

Answer (score 0):

c.getCount() will give you required count.